# Issue sony vaio : greater than (>) and less than (<) french keyboard

Tags: keyboard, sony-vaio, qwerty

Originally my keyboard is QWERTY , and greater than (>) and less than (<) symbols work well, but when I switch my language from english to french ( AZERTY) .
 I don't know where is the location of those keys.
I will be thankful for your help.
Regards!

Comment: which is your original layout? en-us?  in fr and it keyboards, < and > are on the lower left corner, right to the shift key

Comment: the original layout is qwerty  with english

Comment: You don't need to change the layout when you change the language. Once you've changed Windows language to French, you can still go into Regional Settings and set your keyboard type to English so that it matches the letters printed on your keyboard.

Comment: @GAThrawn Actually I want to know the places of (>) (<) in french language in this keyboard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There appears to be no keys on a physically QWERTY keyboard that are mapped to <kbd><</kbd> or <kbd>></kbd> under Windows' AZERTY layout. So the answer basically is, there are no such keys.

If you had a Num Pad on your keyboard, you could use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Num 6</kbd>,<kbd>Num 0</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Num 6</kbd>,<kbd>Num 2</kbd> respectively for <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd>, but since it's a laptop, it most likely doesn't have a Num Pad.

There is a geeky solution for this, however. Just ten steps that you can follow. It shouldn't take more than 20 min of your time.

---

1. Download AutoHotkey program installer from the [official site](http://www.autohotkey.com/). It's free.
2. Install the program. Choose "Express installation" because "Custom installation" can be confusing. Leave the installation options to their defaults.
3. After the program is installed, you need to create an AutoHotkey script. Before that, go to your documents folder and create a folder with the name `AutoHotkey Scripts`. The location or the name of the folder don't matter, what does matter however is that it should not be deleted as long as you want the keys to work.
4. Open that folder you've created, right-click on the empty space, and choose **New > AutoHotkey Script**. A new file is created inviting you to pick a name for it. For example, name it `Angle Brackets` (don't change or remove the file's extension!).
5. Right-click *on* the created file and choose **Edit Script**.
6. A Notepad window should appear. Add the following text *after* the text that is already there.

   > !+1::Send <
   >   !+2::Send >

   so that the last three lines look like this:

   > SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
   >   !+1::Send <
   >   !+2::Send >

   What this scary text means is that <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd>, which are called angle brackets, are going to be mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> respectively.
7. In the Notepad window, go to the **File** menu and click **Save**. You may now close Notepad.
8. Right-click *on* the `Angle Brackets` file again and this time choose **Run Script** (or simply double-click the file).
9. Now, the key combinations for <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> should have been activated, so let's test them. Open any text editor and try whether <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> work.
10. It's not over yet because you need these key combinations to be activated on every Windows startup. Create a shortcut to the `Angle Brackets` file by right-clicking on it and clicking **Create shortcut**. A shortcut is created with a little arrow in its icon. Now, click the Windows' **Start** button, click **All Programs**, right-click the **Startup** folder, and then click **Open**. Drag the created shortcut from the window of the `AutoHotkey Scripts` folder into the window of the **Startup** folder.

---

By repeating steps from 5 to 7 (but this time editing existing text, not adding lines) you can change the key combinations to any key combinations you prefer. In the two lines you added to the script, look at the text that appears before `::Send`. Here is what it means:

- `!` symbol stands for the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key
- `+` symbol stands for the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key
- `1` stands for the <kbd>1</kbd> key and `2` stands for the <kbd>2</kbd> key

You can edit the key combinations by changing, adding, or removing their respective symbols. For example, if you would prefer <kbd>A</kbd> insted of <kbd>1</kbd>, you would replace `1` with `a`. Other symbols/keys you could use are:

- `^` symbol, which stands for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key
- `#` symbol, which stands for the <kbd>Win</kbd> key

Whenever you change the text in `Angle Brackets` file, you should find the AutoHotkey icon in the Windows Tray, which looks like a green square with an "H" in it, right-click on it, and click **Reload This Script** (if you aren't able to find the "H" icon in the Tray, try double-clicking the `Angle Brackets` file).

Comment: Thank you for your answer , no I have no NUM pad on my laptop.

Comment: The sony support suggets to me to try Fn + < / > or  Alt + < / > but no way

Comment: @Angelika (T_T)

Comment: @Angelika I guess I found a solution, stay around!

Comment: Oh great , Really ?

Comment: @Angelika Yeah! There you go!

Comment: @Hume : thank you very very much your answer was perfect after 10 days of search , thank you :)

Comment: @DesmondHume Thanks for this awesome answer you've helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

For French Canadian Keyboard

```
< : right hand ALT + (comma)
> : right hand ALT + (dot)
/ : first key on the left side of Key #1
\ : SHIFT + first key left side of key #1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install [KbdKaz 500](http://www.omega-com.pl/kbdkaz.htm) in French layout edition. During installation you can choose AZERTY keys layout.

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator** 1.4 allows to modify the keys any way you want.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339

Not 100% sure yet if it works on Windows 10.

Update: It actually works! Don't forget to restart computer after installing your own made keyboard layout.

Comment: If you actually read the link you quoted you would know the answer. "Supported Operating System

Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1, Windows Vista, Windows XP, Windows XP Service Pack 1, Windows XP Service Pack 2"

Comment: @DavidPostill, people from the internet have mixed experiences using Windows 8, for some it works, so "supported OS" does not necessarily mean it will not work in newer ones.


JakeGould The answer itself is the binary download. I did include the application name if the link becomes outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by remapping the CapsLock key to the missing key by adding the following registry key.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,56,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00

(Long explanation of the Scancode Map registry key here: http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/2155/Keyboard-Remapping-CAPSLOCK-to-Ctrl-and-Beyond.html)

Worked for me with Windows 10. In English QWERTY, CapsLock becomes a duplicate of the /,| key.

Answer (score -1):

Found this to be an easy way:

Alt 60  <   Less Than

Alt 62  >   Greater Than

I used Alt on left side.

Comment: this is already in the previous answers.

Answer (score -2):

This is the basic layout of an AZERTY keyboard,

[image: azerty]

which is your original layout? en-us?

In fr (azerty) and it (qwerty) keyboards, < and > are on the lower left corner, right to the shift key

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem with my laptop. The following combinations...

```
< : righthand ALT + SHIFT + w
> : righthand ALT + SHIFT + x
```

worked for me. Hope it works for you.