# i can not find keys < and > on hp paviilon 15 azerty keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

i bought an hp laptop pavillon 15. the keyboard is an AZERTY keybord
(image shown below) . The < and > key are normally positioned left the W key.
But in this disposition are combined with ; and : keys.
I can't figure out which combination can use.

[image: my laptop keyboard]

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Your question unnecessarily difficult to understand. It would be helpful to structure your question into separate paragraphs which for example describe the problem, the background information and the actual question separately. Of course this goes for spelling, using upper and lower case letters, grammar etc. as well.

Comment: i can(t type the < (small than) and > (greater than) with my keyboard

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to press the AltGr key in order to be able
to access these keys.

There are more keys like that on your keyboard.

If this didn't solve the problem, please let us know what is your
keyboard language.

Comment: i tried altgr+; al+t; ctrl+; alt+ctrl+;  fn+;. But didnt work. French-french language

Comment: But your keyboard isn't [French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY). Which is it?

Comment: don't know which is.

Comment: Don't you have any information about it? I never saw such a keyboard.

Comment: Just press AltGR together with all the keys one by one, and maybe you will find it.

Comment: i found this post. https://superuser.com/questions/561747/issue-sony-vaio-greater-than-and-less-than-french-keyboard

Comment: That's if you haven't found any key that together with AltGr gives these characters, then you can map them to some other keys. If you have some favorite key-combinations that you would like to use for these characters, let me know and I'll include it here.

Answer (score 0):

Check you keyboard layout.  It could be for a different one.

You can check and change/add the different layout using this tutorial.

> https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-keyboard-layout-windows-10